# Sum strings length from a txt file

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, sum, string-length

I have txt file with names which look like that:

```
Hans
Anna
Vladimir
Michael
Ed
Susan
Janice
Jo
```

I want to print the sum of all the names length:

```
with open(r"C:\people_names.txt", "r") as name_file:
    sum_names = (len(x) for x in name_file)
print(sum(sum_names))
```

The problem is that there is "\n" after every name which count as a letter and the last name dont have "\n",

Thats why I cant do  `len(x)-1`

Will be glad for any suggestions how to do the sum :)

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't recommend using `readlines()` if the file is too big.
You can use `rstrip` to remove the `\n` from the end of each line.

```
with open(r"C:\people_names.txt", "r") as name_file:
    sum_names = [len(x.rstrip('\n')) for x in name_file]
print(sum(sum_names))
```

Comment: Thank you! sounds great!

Comment: Did you try running this code? It returns error.

Comment: @RoshinRaphel Thank you for the note, I updated the answer
```sum_names``` was a generator before which caused the problem

Answer (score 1):

```
with open(r"C:\people_names.txt", "r") as name_file:
    data = name_file.read()  

total_characters = len(data) - data.count("\n")
print(total_characters)
```

Answer (score 0):

Read each line from the file :

```
with open(r"C:\people_names.txt", "r") as name_file:
    name_file = name_file.readlines()
sum_names = [len(x.strip()) for x in name_file]
print(sum(sum_names))
```

`name_file.readlines()` returns a list of lines, and these lines are identified by the newline character. That will take care of your issue.
An alternative solution will be to use `splitlines()` :

```
with open(r"hello.txt", "r") as name_file:
    name_file = name_file.read().splitlines()
sum_names = [len(x) for x in name_file]
print(sum(sum_names))
```

Comment: Thank you very much! so I dont have to do `name_file = name_file.readlines()` if I use the `len(x.strip()` method

Comment: @Ileh then you will have to use name_file = name_file.read() since `with` automatically closes the file handler making it not accessible for the next line